# Getting specific words from a sentence

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a sentence which looks like this {Name=Zeus, Address=Something 21} . I want to get only the words after the = (Zeus Something 21), but it's not working for the both of them. That's my code

```
    String line="";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[=]+([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)");
    for (Entity entity : pq.asIterable()) {
        String placeInfo=entity.getProperties().toString();
        line=placeInfo;
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                result.add(matcher.group());
            }
```

and that's the result i get: =Zeus.
I suppose it's pattern's fault but i don't know what to change... Any ideas?
The placeinfo equals to something that looks like {Name=Something, Address=Something 21} and it's entity properties i'm getting from my datastore.

Comment: Use json parser for this. but the problem is each entity should be in double quotes

Comment: `matcher.group()` ------> `matcher.group(1)` and add the space in `[A-Za-z0-9-_]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex and code seem very close to expected result;

```
String line = "{Name=Zeus, Address=Something 21}";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[=]+([A-Za-z0-9-_ ]+)"); //added space 
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); //did you try group(1)
}
```

Comment: It was helpful but still doesn't get the second word. Maybe i should use the json parser...but thanks anyway!

Comment: Only copy paste below code. output is Zeus \n 
Something 21

Comment: now that i copy paste exactly your code it worked but the thing is that i have mulptiple lines that's why i am using  
String placeInfo=entity.getProperties().toString();
        line=placeInfo;
and when i do that it's not working..I don't know why

Comment: If you give a runnable code on your question, we can give you more help.  On your code line=placeInfo is meaningless you can use placeInfo directly. If you want to append placeInfo to line, use line += placeInfo and use pattern.matcher after loop ends.

Comment: I think you must debug over loop and check placeInfo values. I do not really understand what is not working

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the correct approach? What is the return type of `entity.getProperties()`? If it's a Map or a Properties or a JSON object you are probably best to use an appropriate getter rather than using a regex on the `toString()`.

eg

```
Map<String, String> properties = entity.getProperties();
String name = properties.get("Name");
String address = properties.get("Address");
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("{Name=(.+), Address=(.+)}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("{Name=Zeus, Address=Something 21}");
if (!matcher.matches()) throw new RuntimeException();
String name = matcher.group(1);
String address = matcher.group(2);
```

Comment: Why the downvote? If it's because a JSON library should be used instead take another look at the format (it's not valid JSON)

Comment: I think downvotes owner must reply :) but I think because of pattern "{Name=(.+), Address=(.+)}" is so limited not a general solution.